# Physijs-webpack library fails by require

Tags: webpack, physijs

In the web application I already have some packages declared with "require" and understood by webpack:

- three
- three-orbit-controls

This is how I use it:

```
var THREE = require('three');

var OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);
```

To add physics, I try to add library physijs-webpack:

```
var PhysiJS = require('physijs-webpack')(THREE);
```

It fails at "npm run build" saying:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'physijs-webpack'

In the console (Chrome dev tools) following error is displayed:

```
"app.js:17 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "physijs-webpack"
    at webpackMissingModule (app.js:17)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (app.js:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 460ca68f8e6f1e90ea58:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (html5-entities.js:190)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 460ca68f8e6f1e90ea58:19)
    at module.exports.ctor.super_ (bootstrap 460ca68f8e6f1e90ea58:62)"
```

This is my webpack.config file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/app.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
    }
};
```

Dependencies are:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
        "webpack": "^3.5.4",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
        "yarn": "^0.27.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "physijs": "^0.0.4",
        "physijs-webpack": "^0.0.2",
        "requirejs": "^2.3.4",
        "three": "^0.86.0",
        "three-orbit-controls": "^82.1.0"
    }
}
```

Could you please recommend, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr - you had been using a broken build that was published by someone else. Use `v0.1.0` or above and read the directions at https://github.com/agilgur5/physijs-webpack/

---

Hi there, I'm the creator of the [`physijs-webpack` repo](https://github.com/agilgur5/physijs-webpack/).

Per an [old version of the README](https://github.com/agilgur5/physijs-webpack/tree/d0c62b7228add3a1c6675f39ab71902ab969dc51) and this [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/_drewpowers/status/907719141213200385), my port had been a work-in-progress with a failed build up until September 2018, when I decided to give it a shot again. Someone else had published my repo with a broken build to NPM without telling me, so the package you originally found on NPM was broken.

In September 2018, I rewrote most of the repo and managed to figure out a way to get it to work. At that time, I asked people to install via `agilgur5/physijs-webpack` as I did not have control of the NPM package. Later that month, I was granted control of the package and have now published a v0.1.0 and v0.1.1 that have a successful and working build. Now you can install via `physijs-webpack` and follow the directions of the package or repo to get it working -- i.e. also install `worker-loader` as a `devDependency`.

The old, not-working NPM version (v0.0.2) will also be unpublished shortly to avoid confusion like this.

---

On your Webpack config:

The other answer here says to update your Webpack config, but that is ***incorrect*** and extraneous (it doesn't even have a `.worker.js` extension). `physijs-webpack` actually *specifically* and *intentionally* uses an [in-line loader](https://github.com/agilgur5/physijs-webpack/blob/97ef935581a46ec4019d6e0e6f289f36ec6b2254/webpack.js#L2) so that you *don't* have to update your webpack config at all.

---

On the `physijs` NPM package:

I also noticed you had `physijs` in your `package.json` -- that NPM package was created by the same person and was a duplicate of the `physijs-webpack`. It was unpublished in September 2018 at the same time I was granted ownership of the `physijs-webpack` NPM package.

---

On the `three` integration:

Another thing I noticed was that `three` is in your `package.json`. While this was required for the earlier, not-working version, in the current working version, it is now a `peerDependency`. You don't need to pass `THREE` as an argument anymore, but you will still need to install it since most usage of PhysiJS requires you to use THREE anyway. It has also been pinned to the `r73` release of THREE because that was the last version PhysiJS supported / had compatibility for.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered and worked-around the issue by following the webpack details found @ https://github.com/agilgur5/physijs-webpack

basically ...

```
npm install -S agilgur5/physijs-webpack
```

and

```
npm install -D worker-loader
```

I also had to update my webpack config

```
// webpack.config.js
{
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        use: { loader: 'worker-loader' }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

references:

- https://github.com/agilgur5/physijs-webpack
- https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader

Comment: Hi there, per my answer, you don't need to update your webpack config. `physijs-webpack` actually uses an in-line loader for this exact purpose: so users don't need to change their config.

Also, the worker file in the library does not even have a `.worker.js` extension, so the rule you wrote would not even apply to it (and therefore had no impact on getting it to work). Thanks for answering this question before I had a chance to see it!